# Difference between ArrayListMultimap.create() and RowData = new ArrayList();

Tags: java, list

I would like to ask what is the difference between

`ArrayListMultimap.create()`

And

`RowData = new ArrayList()`.

I know the first one is used for Multimaps and the latter is used for lists but I once used the `ArrayListMultimap.create()` in a code and it can return values like this:

```
{[Color, Fruit], [Pink,Orange]}
```

Whereas the latter returns:

```
[Color,Fruit,Pink,Orange]
```

I was expecting that `RowData = new ArrayList()` can return values the way `ArrayListMultimap.create()` does....

Please enlighten me.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. If you build a car, you won't get a truck. If you build a truck, you won't get a car. Creating an ArrayList will create an ArrayList, not a Multimap. I suggest you read the javadoc of ArrayListMultimap and ArrayList.

Comment: Yeah, I know that they are used for different purposes (ArrayList,Multimap). What I'd like to ask is can an ArrayList return value like this: [[Color,Fruit],[Pink,Orange]]. Is it possible? Or do i need to use something else to make it possible?

Comment: An ArrayList doesn't return anything. Its methods return something. It seems you want a list of lists. And yes, of course it's possible.

Comment: I think you hit it right when you said List of list. That's what I'd like to do actually, thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` its just a simple `List` 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

and `ArrayListMultimap` is a `Multimap` http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html 
implementation based on `ArrayList`.

Basically those two classes provides different api.